# How to rank Revenue based on multiple Criteria. MS Excel

Tags: excel, formula

So I have this data set and I want to rank the revenue of some hotels based on multiple criteria.

So the columns look like this.

```
Day(1-31)   EUCountry    Hotels(1-12)   Revenue(0-100k)
        2          DE              3             34,120 
        6          FI              6             60,358

  ...
  ...

(and so on...)
```

> And I want to calculate the rank of each Hotel within each EUCountry for
>   each Day in terms of Revenue (In a new Columns so it has to be a formula)
>   .

Any Ideas on how should I do this???

Any help would be grateful

Comment: create a pivot table. Put Day, EUCountry  and Hotels (1-12) in ROWS category (in that order) and Revenue in VALUES category. Value-sort Revenue from highest to lowest

Comment: I forgot to say that I need this in a new columns so it has to be done with a formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the COUNTIFS forumla as a kind of "RANK_IF" formula. See e.g. this example: https://exceljet.net/formula/rank-if-formula . This is an alternative tutorial: https://excelchamps.com/blog/conditional-ranking-sumproduct-rank-if/
Hope that works!